# using DiffMerge

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, ankhsvn, diffmerge

I would like to be able to edit conflicts using DiffMerge but when I try, VS (2010) complains I need to configure an external tool.  It states I should do this from the Tools/Options/Source Control/Subversion menu.  Trouble is, I don't have a [Source Control/Subversion], I have only [Plug-in Selection].

I found [[this article](http://damieng.com/blog/2007/06/15/diffmerge-is-free-try-it-with-ankhsvn)] that indicates how to do the configuration but refers to the same menu entry...

Can anyone tell me what I need to install/configure to make this work?

Comment: What version of AnkhSVN do you have installed?

Comment: @Sander: I installed it using the Extension Manager so it's the latest: 2.1.101.29.17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure you have AnkhSVN selected in Tools / Options / Source Control / Plug-in Selection. Then choose your diff tool in
Tools / Options / Source Control / Subversion User tools. [image]

Comment: I cannot do as you suggest for the reason I explained: there is nothing under the Tools/Options/Source Control, except for [Plug-in Selection].  I seem to be missing the [Subversion] section everyone is talking about and I can't figure out why...

Comment: What value do you see in the Plug-in Selection?

Comment: "AnkhSVN - Subversion support for Visual Studio"

Comment: @Ekkis: I have added a screenshot. You should have the two Subversion entries under the Plug-in Selection on the left side. If you do not have them there, most likely your Ankh installation is broken and uninstalling and installing it again could help.

Comment: reinstalling solved the problem.  I now see the sections in your screenshot and was able to configure my diff/merge tool.  thanks a bunch!